# fwrite and fread dynamic allocated char array with numbers and symbols in it, read only 4 bytes instead of 9

Tags: c, data-structures, fwrite, fread

Lets say I have this boardValues array in structure

```
typedef struct Stack
{
    char* boardValues;
    int size;
    char* playerSymbol;
    int count;
    int turnsCount;

}Stack;
```

I aloccate memory and inicialize values with this funcion which I put on a loop and array gets values from 1 - 9;

```
void push( Stack *g, char value )
{
    char *temp = realloc( g->boardValues, ( g->size + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        g->boardValues = temp;
        g->boardValues[g->size] = value;
        ++g->size;
    }
}
```

Then as a tictoe game goes on, boardValues lets say get this value boardValues = ['X','O','O,'X','X','O',6,7,8,9]

I need to save this data in binary and later load from it, here is the funcions:

```
int saveToBinary(Stack *g) {
    if (strcmp("continue",name) != 0){
        strncat(name,".bin",5);
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(name, "wb");
        if(fp != NULL){
            fwrite(g->boardValues ,1 ,sizeof(g->boardValues) ,fp);
            fwrite(g->playerSymbol ,1 ,sizeof(g->playerSymbol) ,fp);
            fwrite(&g->count ,1 ,sizeof(&g->count) ,fp);
            fwrite(&g->turnsCount ,1 ,sizeof(&g->turnsCount) ,fp);
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
} 

int loadFromBinary(Stack *g){

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(saveName, "rb");
    if (fp != NULL){
        fread(g->boardValues ,sizeof(g->boardValues) ,1, fp); 
        fread(g->playerSymbol ,sizeof(g->playerSymbol) ,1 ,fp);
        fread(&g->count ,1 ,sizeof(g->count) ,fp);
        fread(&g->turnsCount ,1 ,sizeof(g->turnsCount) ,fp);
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    else { 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is I get only first 4 char symbols other 2 becomes garbage(I think) and then I get last numbers from it, so somehow some symbols dissapear. I tried changing fread to fread(g->boardValues ,sizeof(char) ,9, fp); but then other values like turnsCount or count becomes garbage

Comment: Hmm.  `sizeof(g->boardValues)` will only return the size of the pointer, not the size of the pointed-to items.  Also, why is the `realloc()` assigning to `boardValues` considering `sizeof(int)` when it's a `char *` ?

Comment: I am still new to c language, but about realloc() I though if I make sizeof(char) the int wouldn't fit in char array since int is 4 bytes and char is 1 so I assigned more memory. Is it not a correct approach?

Comment: I just tried it, and it seems it works with sizeof(char), but why?

Comment: if you only needed room for so many characters but you ask for room for so many `int`, then you're asking for 4 (or 8) times as much memory as you actually needed.  It will work, but is wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(g->boardValues)` and `sizeof(g->playerSymbol)` are the size of the pointers, not the alloated buffers.

You should read/write the size of buffers first, then read/write contents for the buffers. Be careful not to forget to allocate buffer before reading.

example for `g->boardValues`:

save:

```
fwrite(&g->size ,1 ,sizeof(g->size) ,fp);
fwrite(g->boardValues ,1 ,g->size ,fp);
```

load:

```
fread(&g->size ,1 ,sizeof(g->size) ,fp);
g->boardValues = malloc(g->size);
fread(g->boardValues ,1 ,g->size ,fp);
```

(error handling is omitted)